# Ingest graphql.operation.name to request data in open telemetry

Tags: graphql, instruments, open-telemetry, hotchocolate

I'm  working on my project's instrument with hot chocolate(GraphQL), and as part of the process, we're exporting the open telemetry to Azure Application Insight. I have a question regarding the request data:

```
{
   "name":"Request",
   "time":"2023-07-27T20:58:44.4824818Z",
   "sampleRate":100,
   "iKey":"e0aadde8-4d01-4aeb-b1f4-455ba57e99e2",
   "tags":{
      "ai.operation.id":"2936e8c6a52c6bfc2193ce4409a13321",
      "ai.user.userAgent":"PostmanRuntime/7.32.3",
      "ai.cloud.role":"[default-namespace]/default-service",
      "ai.cloud.roleInstance":"2a979b10-b1d7-4bbc-b3f4-3ee75e91ca29",
      "ai.internal.sdkVersion":"dotnet6.0.20:otel1.5.0:ext1.0.0-beta.13",
      "ai.operation.name":"POST /graphql/",
      "ai.location.ip":null
   },
   "data":{
      "baseType":"RequestData",
      "baseData":{
         "id":"08f6e292b3ac84d7",
         "name":"POST /graphql/",
         "duration":"00:00:02.4003054",
         "success":true,
         "responseCode":"200",
         "url":"http://localhost:16621/graphql/",
         "properties":{
            "http.flavor":"1.1",
            "_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name: X,Ver:\u00271.1\u0027)"
         },
         "ver":2
      }
   }
}
```

How to elegantly include "graphql.operation.name" as one of the properties in the request data?

Comment: Got a response from HotChocolate Slack community https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/issues/1596#issuecomment-982442279